# How to check if user inputted a command correctly - C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm working on an adventure-type text game in a console application for C#.

I need a method to test if the user put in a command correctly, and if they didn't to test again.

I'm trying this right now:

```
do
{
    Response = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (Response.ToLower())
    {
        case "hallway":
            Location = Locations[2];
            Console.WriteLine("You decide to get some fresh air, and step out of the dance room and into the hallway." + "\n" + "There's no one here.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("Command List: Look, Look at, Move, Check Status");
            Console.ResetColor();
            ResponseTester();
            break;
        case "dance room":
            //[Other code here]
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't understand that.");
            break;
    }
}
while (Response.ToLower() != "hallway" || Response.ToLower() != "dance room");
```

However it's not very reliable, as when I try it with if/else statements or other uses, it will only test once. Is there a better way to test?

Comment: You can have user input and syntax check located inside infinite loop `while(true) { ... }`. Otherwise it's not clear what is the problem with *"it will only test once"*.

Comment: @Sintar If the user doesn't input correctly, it won't reset the loop so they can input properly, is what I mean. Like if I input move, and then don't spell "hallway" correctly, it wont try again and only outputs that it didnt understand.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rewrite it as follows

```
var invalid = true;
while (invalid )
{
  Response = Console.ReadLine();
  switch (Response.ToLower())
    {
      case "hallway":
      Location = Locations[2];
      Console.WriteLine("You decide to get some fresh air, and step out of the dance room and into the hallway." + "\n" + "There's no one here.");
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
      Console.WriteLine("Command List: Look, Look at, Move, Check Status");
      Console.ResetColor();
      ResponseTester();
      invalid = false;
      break;
    case "dance room":
      //[Other code here]
      invalid = false;
      break;
    default:
      Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't understand that.");
      break;
    }
  }
```

but beyond that, really getting the input needs to be separate from processing the input for game design. Set up an array or list of acceptable words and just test against that, then process separately.

so like this

```
private List<string> validWords = new List<string>{"hallway","dance room"};

private string GetInput()
{
  var response = string.Empty;
  while (true)
    {
      response = Console.ReadLine();
      if (validWords.Contains(response))
        {
          break;
        }
    }
    return response;
}

private void ProcessInput(string response)
{
   //switch statements go here
}
```

Comment: The second method seems much more efficient actually. Can you explain a little bit more what's going on here- I'm still somewhat new to C#, and I'm not sure I'm doing it right?

Comment: Well, skipping what language it is entirely, in any sort of programming you want separation of concerns. So receiving input is separate from processing input. Basically you'd have an outer loop that perpetually calls get input then once it receives a string back calls ProcessInput. The get input checks to see if the word entered is in the list of valid words and forces them to continue inputting until they do enter a correct one. That's the point of 

>while (true)
in that it will keep repeating until it hits the break in finding the valid word